# How to mount floating shelves on plaster and lath walls via keyhole mounting system?

Tags: mounting, lath-and-plaster

I bought a floating shelf which came with drywall anchors and screws. The shelf has keyhole slots on the back so it's supposed to slot in and rest on the screws. That being said, I live in an old building with plaster-and-lath walls. I'm used to hanging heavy items using toggle bolts, however I've never used toggle bolts with a keyhole mounting system. Should I go about this using a nut and small washers to give me that space for the bolt to stick out from the wall? Or are there better fasteners to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: How much load do you plan to put on these shelves? What are the key hole slots made off?  I am more concerned about the key holes giving up then the screws on the wall.

Comment: I live in an old house with plaster & lath walls and I just drive a screw into the wall where I want to hang something. I've never used toggle bolts, drywall anchors, or a stud finder (well, I tried the stud finder - it finds lath everywhere, so it's of very little use). I hung up 8' x 8' shelves on metal stanchions years ago and severely overloaded them with books & paper & cruft and never had an issue with screws pulling out... YMMV. i.e., just drive screws and hang the shelf...

Comment: The shelves' total weight is 35 lbs, and can hold 90 lbs, so 125 lbs total. Key hole slots are steel I believe.